# I want to add a form of select components in the header (top navigation) in my filament php admin dashboard

Tags: php, laravel-filament, filamentphp

## This is my NavBar

I want to add a form with a select element that will help in loading data. The filament documentation only shows how to add a search option.

[image]

How do I go about it?

## I want to make something like this in filament php

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Filament does not have any built-in tools for inserting select in top navigation bar. However, it is possible to implement it manually. You can insert any code in top nav using [render hooks](https://filamentphp.com/docs/3.x/support/render-hooks).

There are some related hooks:

panels::global-search.after - After the global search select, inside the topbar
panels::global-search.before - Before the global search select, inside the topbar
panels::topbar.end - End of the topbar container
panels::topbar.start - Start of the topbar container

In your case `panels::global-search.before` will insert code near global search select. For example you can add this into the `boot()` method of `AppServiceProvider`:

```
use Filament\Support\Facades\FilamentView;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Blade;
 
FilamentView::registerRenderHook(
    'panels::global-search.before',
    fn (): string => Blade::render('@livewire(\'options-selector\')'),
);
```

You can render any blade view in the hook, but if you want to use the value which user picks in the select, it would better creating Livewire component. This component will render the select element, and when user select the value, it will save the value into the session and then dispatch an event "option-selected". For example:

```
namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Illuminate\View\ComponentAttributeBag;
use Livewire\Component;

class OptionSelector extends Component
{
    public $selectedOption = null;

    public function mount()
    {
        $this->selectedOption = session()->get("selected_option");
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('components.options-selector', [
            'options' => $this->getOptions(),
        ]);
    }

    public function getOptions(): array
    {
    return [
        1 => "Option 1",
        2 => "Option 2",
        3 => "Option 3",
    ];
    }

    public function getExtraAttributeBag(): ComponentAttributeBag
    {
        return new ComponentAttributeBag();
    }

    public function optionSelected()
    {
        $this->dispatch("option-selected");

        session()->put("selected_option", $this->selectedOption);
        
        //This method is called each time when user picks an option in the select you can debug it here
        //dump($this->selectedOption);
    }
}
```

Here is the blade template file which must be located in resources/views/components/options-selector.blade.php:

```
<div>
    <x-filament::input.wrapper
        class="fi-fo-select"
        :attributes="\Filament\Support\prepare_inherited_attributes($this->getExtraAttributeBag())"
    >
        <x-filament::input.select wire:model="selectedOption" wire:change="optionSelected">
            <option value="">
                Not selected
            </option>

            @foreach ($options as $id => $option)
                <option value="{{ $id }}">{{ $option }}</option>
            @endforeach
        </x-filament::input.select>
    </x-filament::input.wrapper>
</div>
```

And register this component in `boot()` method of AppServiceProvider:

```
Livewire::component('option-selector', OptionSelector::class);
```

It is the rendering part, now you will see the select and be able to dump the selected option in the component. Then, you can catch the `option-selected` Livewire event on required pages and apply the selected option to your Eloquent query or etc. All Livewire components have `$listeners` property, which you can use to listen Livewire events.

You can read more about events in Livewire on their official site: https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/events.

For example, applying selected option to query for some resource index page looks like this:

```
namespace App\Filament\Resources\ReportResource\Pages;

use Filament\Resources\Pages\ListRecords;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;

class ListRecords extends ListRecords
{
    public $listeners = [
        'option-selected' => "optionSelected"
    ];

    public function optionSelected()
    {
        //Here you need to initiate page updating
        //Switching to the first page will re-render the page.
        $this->resetPage();
    
        //Also you can make redirect to the page itself
        //     return redirect(request()->header('Referer'));
    }

    protected function getTableQuery(): ?Builder
    {
    $selectedOption = session()->get("selected_option");

        $query = parent::getTableQuery());
        
        if($selectedOption !== null){
            //apply the option to the query
        }else{
            //Show nothing if nothing selected
            $query->whereRaw("false");
        }

    return $query;
    }
}
```

The code above will work only on pages that is extended from Livewire component. A resource is not Livewire component so you have to implement this directly on resource each page, like List, Edit, Create, etc. All this tested in Filament 3.